# Как сделать запрос к БД имея строку в которой содержатся name и value?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Сделав ajax-запрос получил из формы строку, в которой идет name и value выбранного input radio: "genres=detective&publishing=80&pages=300&prices=1000hrv&authors=Shekspir". Но проблема пока в том, что в БД у меня в таблице критерий Детективы написаны на русском языке, так же в publishing(дата публикации) 80(получить все книги из восьмидесятых) по идее как бы нужен промежуток 1980-1989 чтобы сделать запрос позже с BETWEEN, и как я понял, в value необходимо прописать такой промежуток. Так же и с остальными критериями страницы, цены идут в промежутке. Потом из строки все данные отсортировать по переменным и с ними уже работать в самом запросе. Я себе это так представляю, но может это нереализуемо и поэтому хочу спросить как решить мою проблему.

```
SELECT * FROM `book_items` WHERE `genre_book`= 'Детективи' AND `year_publishing_book` BETWEEN 1980 AND 1989 AND `number_of_page` BETWEEN 200 AND 300 AND `price` BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 AND `author`= 'Вільям Шекспір';

CREATE TABLE `book_items` (
  `id_book` int NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `genre_book` varchar(35) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `year_publishing_book` int NOT NULL,
  `number_of_page` int NOT NULL,
  `price` int NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language_book` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_description` varchar(400) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `book_items` (`id_book`, `book_name`, `genre_book`, `year_publishing_book`, `number_of_page`, `price`, `author`, `language_book`, `short_description`) VALUES
(1, 'Мізері', 'Жахи', 2021, 384, 210, 'Стівен Кінг', 'українська', 'В основі сюжету твору закладено стосунки двох героїв книги — популярного письменника Пола Шелдона та його психопатичної шанувальниці Енні Вілкс.'),
(2, 'Містер Мерседес', 'Детектив', 2020, 544, 339, 'Стівен Кінг', 'українська', 'Книга розповідає історію відставного поліцейського, який після виходу на пенсію намагається докопатися до істини в нерозкритому злочині, який вчинив водій «Мерседеса».'),
(3, 'Якщо тече кров', 'Фантастика', 2021, 512, 275, 'Стівен Кінг', 'англійська', 'Увесь свій виграш Крейґ витратив на «айфон» останнього покоління. І, не приймаючи жодних відмов, подарував його доброму другові — літньому мільярдерові, містеру Герріґену. Але згодом чоловік помирає. Того ж вечора Крейґ отримує повідомлення із кількома буквами. SMS надійшло з номера містера Герріґена '),
(4, 'Сяйво', 'Фантастика', 1977, 512, 729, 'Стівен Кінг', 'українська', 'У цього шикарного готелю в горах — лиха слава. Колись там сталася страшна трагедія. Тому взимку в його стінах лишаються тільки привиди...'),
(5, '11/22/63', 'Романи', 2011, 911, 310, 'Стівен Кінг', 'українська', '22 листопада 1963 року — дата вбивства Джона Кеннеді. Пролунали три постріли — і світ змінився назавжди. Сьогодення. ')
```

Comment: Текст заголовка вопроса не вяжется с примером в теле вопроса.
Я не понял вопроса. 
Есть пример кода, который не заработал?

Comment: *проблема пока в том, что в БД у меня в таблице критерий Детективы написаны на русском языке, так же в publishing(дата публикации) 80(получить все книги из восьмидесятых) по идее как бы нужен промежуток 1980-1989* Значит, должна существовать таблица, которая переводит эту хрень во вменяемую и пригодную к работе форму. Выложите пример - CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, и требуемый результат для показанных исходных данных и значения в input.

Comment: Прикрепил к посту CREATE и INSERT + запрос который я хочу прописать добавив в него значения полученные от пользователя

Comment: Нужно писать условия через скобки.

 `(price BETWEEN 80 AND 89) AND (number BETWEEN 200 AND 300) AND (....)` и т.д.

Comment: @DrMcSheen В данном случае - необязательно. Вот если бы в строке отбора были перемешаны AND и OR - тогда да.

Comment: Ваш запрос в принципе верный. https://dbfiddle.uk/qdYfV0YW Есть только пара моментов. (1) Неясно, откуда взялось ограничение на количество страниц - в строке, полученной как input, ничего похожего нет. (2) В таблице нет ни одной записи, которая соответствовала бы одновременно всем заданным критериям.

Comment: В любом случае нужна таблица трансляции текста из input в текст в запросе. Например, `('detective','Детективи', NULL), ('80', '1980', (1989))`. Возможно, должна существовать отдельная таблица для каждого фильтруемого поля...

Comment: Ну соответствующей записи нет, потому что думал сначала решить как реализовать запрос интегрировав в него значения, но как вы посоветовали, тут нужно именно в таблице добавлять колонку cо значениями value.